# xml page cannot be displayed

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pr7.xsl"?>

<patients>
    <patient1>
        <name>
            <fname>Kakar</fname>
            <lname>Nyori</lname>
        </name>
        <age>20</age>
        <ssn>20202</ssn>
        <room>101</room>
        <id>2929</id>
        <groupno>22</groupno>
        <address>Mathikere</address>
    </patient1>
</patients>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Patient Information</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>ssn</th>
                        <th>room</th>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>groupno</th>
                        <th>address</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="patients/patient1/name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="patients/patient1/age"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="patients/patient1/ssn"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="patients/patient1/room"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="patients/patient1/id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="patients/patient1/groupno"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="patients/patient1/address"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I view this in chrome, it does not throw any errors. But in the internet explorer it throws this error:

```
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The namespace prefix is not allowed to start with the reserved string "xml". Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/ad...

 <xml:template match="/patients">
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me solve this. I will really appreciate if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Is IE looking at an old version of the file? The error message says `xml:template`, but your file says `xsl:template`.

Comment: Try clearing your cache. Try giving the full URL for the XSL file and see what happens.